# Strange behavior with POST query

Tags: android, post

Item **id_category** isn't sent to the server, but other items are sent no problem.

add.php:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8");
require_once('../php/mysql_conect.php');
$use_db=mysql_query("use open_service;");

$date=date("Y-m-d");
$time=date("H:i:s");

$insert=mysql_query("insert into records(id_category,name,phone,device_id,address,text,publish_date,publish_time) value('$_POST[id_categoty]','$_POST[name]','$_POST[phone]','$_POST[device_id]','$_POST[address]','$_POST[text]','$date','$time');");
?>
```

Part of My code:

> //Get id device
>
> ```
>        *TelephonyManager telMgr=(TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
>        String device_id = telMgr.getDeviceId().toString();
>
>
>        name_post = name.getText().toString();
>        phone_post=phone.getText().toString();
>        address_post=address.getText().toString();
>        comment_post=comment.getText().toString();
>        String id_category="1";
>
>     // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
>                     HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
>                     httpclient.getParams().setParameter("http.protocol.version",
> ```
>
> HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
>                           httpclient.getParams().setParameter("http.socket.timeout", new
>   Integer(2000));
>                           httpclient.getParams().setParameter("http.protocol.content-charset",
>   "UTF-8");
>                           HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.100.100.20/test/mobile/add.php");
>
> ```
>                     try {
>                             // Add your data
>                             List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(6);
>                             nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name_post));
>                             nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("phone", phone_post));
>                             nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("address", address_post));
>                             nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("text", comment_post));
>                             nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("device_id", device_id));
>                             nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id_category", id_category));<--It's don send to
> ```
>
> the server
>                                   httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, "UTF-8"));
>
> ```
>                             response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
>                //Создаем уведомление
>             Toast toast=Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Заявка успешно отправлена", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
>             toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, -200);
>             toast.show();
>
>             //Возвращаемся а предыдущие Activity
>              Intent intent= new Intent();
>              intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), EservisActivity.class);
>              startActivity(intent);
>
>                     }*
> ```

Comment: How do you know it's not sent to the server? If I were you I would inspect `add.php` carefully.

Comment: Show the Request structure your PHP webservice expect from Android clients?

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in `add.php`: `$_POST[id_categoty]` instead of `$_POST[id_category]`